# Create a Presto table with a column as an Array datatype

Tags: presto

How does one create a table in Presto with one of the columns having an Array datatype?

For example:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  (ID BIGINT, ARRAY_COL ARRAY)...

Answer (score 8):

*Edit*

The syntax for array type is `array(element_type)`, like this:

```
create table memory.default.t (a array(varchar));
```

*Original answer*

The syntax for array type is `array<element_type>`, like this:

```
create table memory.default.t (a array<varchar>);
```

Note: the connector in which you create the table must support the array data type and not every connector supports it.